# C# Should I make a second class for single properties when my first class has an object array?

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, object, memory-management

So basically I have this one class called Animal.
In this class I have strings **a,b,c,x,y,z**;

I want to make an object array for this program so I make one called arr.

For **a,b,c,x and y** I want to have different values for each object array elements.

I.e.:  `arr[0].a` will be different than `arr[1].a`, which is different than `arr[2].a` etc.

However, for the property **z**, I only want to use one value for the whole of the program, I.e: arr[0].z is the only z value that I want to use. Currently I just call arr[0].z and never use any other number in [].

Is this bad practice and should I make a whole new class, just for property z so that I don't waste memory space? Are there any other problems associated with not using any of the other values of z?

Comment: Memory space is the least concern. The reason why it's bad design is because `z` doesn't describe any property of an animal. It's as if you tried to save species, age, colour and speed of light in a single object.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So do I refer to z as just z now, and not arr.z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the z variable static and in the constructor of you class simply initialize with this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your class in this way.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string A { get; } // related to instance
    public string B { get; }
    public string C { get; }
    public string X { get; }
    public string Y { get; }

    public string Z          // gets or sets static variable which will affect all animals.
    {
        get { return _z; }
        set { _z = value; }
    }

    private static string _z;
}
```

Is this bad practice ?

Without context we cant say its *always* bad design or not. But generally, yes its bad design.

Comment: you should refer to capital `Z`. like this `arr[2].Z = ""`. @Nuthead